# Session becomes null

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session

My session becomes null. Here is how I assign it in a MVC project on login:

```
Session["connectionString"] = someString;
Session.Timeout = 70;
```

The, in a class library I use it:

```
HttpContext.Current.Session["connectionString"].ToString().
```

But, after some time I get null reference exception.

In the web.config I have:

```
<sessionState timeout="70"/>
```

Why do I get null reference exception.

Comment: Why in the name of Thor would you store the connectionstring in the session?!

Comment: Could you define "some time"? is 2 minutes, 21 minutes, 71 minutes...?

Comment: Usually it goes in the web.config and that's it. At least you have something like one different database per user and you actually need a different connection string per user session.

Comment: @ivowiblo Well that's the thing. Each of my users has different database. I mean database with the same structure, but with different data.

Comment: That's a lot of dbs (or just few users)

Comment: @ivowiblo Just a few users :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are storing the session in memory (which is the default mode) everytime you recompile the application, the web server restarts the application domain and everything that you have stored in session is lost.

Comment: Ok, and what is the alternative place for storing the session?

Comment: It depends on what you need to store and your specific application requirements.

Comment: But that should not cause HttpContext.Current.Session to become null so this is not the answer, although accepted.